# How to implement JSON Path with conditional value in RestAssured(instead of array index using a value)

Tags: java, arrays, cucumber, rest-assured, jsonpath

How to implement JSON Path with conditional value in RestAssured(instead of array index using a value)

Here in the below example Cucumber file, I am trying to match the response fields with array index using a value.

For ex, in the first run group.showGroupItems[3].showId will be 183040. In the next run, group.showGroupItems[2].showId value will be 183040. Here the value  '183040' will have different array index in every run.

Similarly, in the first run group.showGroupItems[0].title will be Clearwise. In the next run, group.showGroupItems[2].title value will be Clearwise. Here the value will 'Clearwise' will have different array index in every run.

Similarly, in the first run profileLevels[2].profileType will be 'ADULT'. In the next run, profileLevels[4].profileType value will be 'ADULT'. Here the value will 'ADULT' will have different array index in every run.

I want my code to have JSON Path conditional value and want to be dynamic. I want in the below way with a condition , how can I change the logic for the method verifyResponseBody() in UtilFile using Java? How can I achieve it JSON Path with the below conditional values?

```
     group.showGroupItems[i].showId==183040
     group.showGroupItems[i].title==Clearwise
     profileLevels[i].profileType==ADULT
```

**UtilFile:**

```
public void verifyResponseBody (Map < String, String > data) throws JsonPathException 
{
  SoftAssert softAssert = new SoftAssert();
  for (String field : data.keySet()) {
  softAssert.assertEquals(response.getBody().jsonPath().getString(field), 
  data.get(field));
 }
  softAssert.assertAll();
}
```

**Cucumber file:**

```
 And I see response matches for fields
| group.showGroupItems[3].showId | 180340 |
| group.showGroupItems[0].title | Clearwise |
| profileLevels[2].profileType | ADULT |
```

**Common Stepdefintion File:**

```
@Then("I see response matches for fields")
public void i_see_response_matches_for_fields(DataTable data) {
apiUtil.verifyResponseBody(data.asMap());
}
```

**JSON data**

```
{
  "group":{
  "id":608,
  "platformType":"all",
  "showGroupType":"default",
  "title":"All Shows",
  "showGroupItems":[
     {
        "showId":19923,
        "filepathShowGroupItemLogo":null,
        "title":"Clearwise",
        "showGroupId":705
     },
     {
        "showId":18454,
        "filepathShowGroupItemLogo":null,
        "title":"Roll It",
        "showGroupId":705
     },
     {
        "showId":183040,
        "filepathShowGroupItemLogo":null,
        "title":"The Dog",
        "showGroupId":705
      }
    ]
  },
  "profileLevels":[
   {
     "title":"Adult",
     "profileType":"ADULT"
   },
   {
     "title":"Older Kids",
     "profileType":"KIDS"
   },
   {
     "title":"Younger Kids",
     "profileType":"YOUNGER_KIDS"
   }
  ]
}
```

Comment: it's better if you can provide response. I'm kind of lost in text. :'(

Comment: @lucas-nguyen-17 : I have added the JSON response

Comment: So, what you want is replace index `i` by `condition`. For example,  `group.showGroupItems[i].showId==183040` --> what is the condition to extract `showId`?

Comment: Earlier in cucumber file I was passing | group.showGroupItems[3].showId | 180340 |...For value 183040, array index[3] keeps changing. Sometimes it gives array index[2] for value 183040. Yes I want to replace i by condition. I want a code in such a way its dynamic for all fields, not only for this JSON response, but can be used for also for other JSON response.

Comment: For ex I wanted something like this | group.showGroupItems[*].showId | 180340  |, where *  indicates which will search for all showId's whose value is equal to 183040. Is this something possible in Cucumber Datatable? I tried but didn't work out. It gave me an cucumber exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can achieve that with some changes in your code:

- Cucumber file: No asterisk `*`

```
| group.id                    | 608       |
| group.platformType2         | all       |
| group.showGroupItems.showId | 180340    |
| group.showGroupItems.title  | Clearwise |
| profileLevels.profileType   | ADULT     |
```

- Utils file:

```
public void verifyResponseBody(Map<String, Object> data) {
    SoftAssert softAssert = new SoftAssert();
    for (String field : data.keySet()) {
        try {
            List<?> list = response.getBody().jsonPath().getList(field);
            Object value = data.get(field);
            softAssert.assertTrue(list.contains(value),
                    String.format("%s doesn't contain '%s'", list, value));
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            softAssert.assertEquals(response.getBody().jsonPath().get(field), data.get(field));
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            System.out.printf("Key %s is wrong \n", field);
        }

    }
    softAssert.assertAll();
}
```

Comment: I am getting error at line number 4   List<?> list = response.getBody().jsonPath().getList(field);

"java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class java.util.List (java.lang.String and java.util.List are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')"

Comment: @lucas-nguyeb-17 This code works perfectly fine, but suppose say if I want to check just one value in JSON file { success : true }, then what is the change I need to perform in the above code. Basically I also wanted to check success = true. Was getting the error java.lang.AssertionError: The following asserts failed:

Expected : true
Actual   : true

Comment: Something like this in cucumber file | success   |  true  |

Comment: I guess the problem comes from compare String `true` vs boolean `true`. I don't know how cucumber covert from `DataTable` to `Map`, does it change the data type or not. You expect `verifyResponseBody` method works in generic way, but it's quite hard, because we don't have ant method to check data type of valuen in json at compile time by `if-else`, we have to verify it at run-time via `try-catch`.

Comment: I double check in my machine, it works fine, no issue when comparing boolean, b/c both 2 value are `Boolean`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248849/discussion-between-wilson-and-lucas-nguyen-17).

Answer (score 0):

Use asterisk/star `*`

```
| group.showGroupItems[*].showId | 180340    |
| group.showGroupItems[*].title  | Clearwise |
| profileLevels[*].profileType   | ADULT     |
```

it gives you list of values and you can then assert that expected value is in this list

Comment: I tried with asterisk, it didn't work.

Comment: has * worked for you anytime while trying in Cucumber DataTable

Comment: what about two dots `group.showGroupItems..showId`